# Postman Collection Runner - How to Save Test Runs to import them back later

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

How can I save a particular test run so that I can import it later using Import Test Run button on the Runs Tab of Postman Collection Runner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question) I found it, but it did take a while)

Here it is:

[image]

Comment: yeah, totally agree)

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version (5.5.0), this can also be done inside the `Run Results` section on the Collection Runner by pressing the "Export Results" button.

[image]